# Relations between executables, static libraries and shared libraries

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am writing a build system for a project and I am not sure about the links between executables, static libraries and shared libraries.

For me there are three affirmations:

- An executable can use both static and shared libraries.
- A static library can use both static and shared libraries.
- A shared library can only use static libraries.

I have still doubts about the third affirmation...

Can you enlighten me on this?

Comment: Note also that on Linux atleast, it's pretty rare that you statically link `glibc` (the GNU std C library)

Comment: @Jite Thanks, I was desperately looking for an example, when I had one under my nose!

Comment: Np, note though that in some cases you really want to statically link glibc (to be more "binary portable"), so it is possible, at the cost of binary size.

Comment: What platforms are your build system targeting? These things can be slightly platform specific so I think it might help people to give more accurate answers about the details by providing information about that.

Comment: @Laserallan This is a build system for a raspberry pi target (but not only) and which can also build host binaries (utilities...). So it is hard to be specific!

Comment: Will it ever be built on a windows platform? That's generally the one behaving differently in the details.

Comment: @Laserallan Ho no sorry, only for Unix platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a static library's basically like linking a `.o` or `.obj` file: all the implementation's linked into the using application or library at that specific point in time.  Changes made to the static library after that time won't be picked up automatically by the code that linked it... the latter would need to be relinked for the changes to be incorporated.

Shared libraries defer the linking until runtime, which means every time the code using a shared library invokes some functionality within it, the version of the shared library which is found at runtime is utilised.  As long as the changes don't affect the public API, you can replace a shared library and applications that find it at runtime will pick up the updates/changes without themselves having to be modified/relinked.

So, yes an executable can use both, a static library can use both, and your ***third "affirmation" is wrong: a shared library can also use both***.  It just means the shared library itself may use a snapshot of functionality from a static library, or it may find other functionality from another shared library at runtime.